# Deploy flask project with Apache Server on Windows Server

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have some problem with a deployment of an flask project.
Everything in developer mode, works fine.

But on Windows Server it doesnt works.

I have C:\Project\My_project with inside:

3 folder

- static
- templates
- uploads

1 file

- app.py

And another folder --> C:\Project\wsgi_scripts with the file app.wsgi

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:\\Project\\My_project')
from app import app as application
```

And i did another file called **myproject.conf** under C:\Apache\conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName My_IP
    WSGIScriptAlias /app C:/Project/wsgi_scripts/app.wsgi
    <Directory C:/Project/My_project>
        AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And under httpd.conf of Apache server, i append this script

```
LoadFile "C:/Python/python311.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Python/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Python"
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
Include conf/myproject.conf
```

Also on httpd.conf -->
DocumentRoot "C:\Project\My_project"
DirectoryIndex templates\login.html

The problems is that when I query the server IP, only the login page works

Trying to login, routes are not executed

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much